# How to override Unslider's arrows styling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, unslider

I am using *multiple* instances of **[Unslider](http://unslider.com/)** on a website I am working on, and one of them needs to have navigation arrows. I added the arrows but now I can't style them, they seem to be inaccessible trough CSS. No `!important;` rules work either.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="unslider">
    <div class="slider">
       <ul>
          <li>
             <!-- slide content -->
          </li>
          <li>
             <!-- slide content -->
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my SCSS (***based upon generated markup from the plugin itself***):

```
.unslider {
    .slider {
        // slide styling
    }
    .unslider-arrow {
        background: tomato !important;
    }
}
```

And my initialization:

```
$('.slider').unslider({
   autoplay: true, delay: 7000,
   arrows: true,
   nav: false,
})
```

---

### Here is a [**Fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/cq5p2g1e/)

---

> **NOTE:** All of the samples are just blank code, which size has been reduced in order to help better and quicker understanding.

No matter what I do, my SCSS(CSS) can't reach the arrows.

> **SOLUTION:** As Marcos described in his answer, You should be very careful about your CSS hierarchy. If you are adding custom containers, unslider might mix-up your selectors slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrows are not children elements of the `.slider`. container.

To achieve what you want, the SCSS hierarchy should look like this:

```
.unslider {
        .unslider-arrow {
            background: tomato ;
        }
}
```

Your original code seems to be adding a `.slider` parent that you don't need.

**Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cq5p2g1e/2/**

Comment: I have just made an edit to my SCSS, this is what it looks like now, and it still doesn't work for me locally.

Comment: See the arrows are not childrens of `.slider`. If don't work in your localhost you need to share the correct code or share a working example reproducing the issue.

Comment: So, are you here ?

Comment: Sorry, I had to be away for an hour. I just came back, did a full refresh wiping the cache (did that before as well but..) and voila - the buttons turned tomatoish. This is really strange, I am starting to think it is something related to the Mozilla Firefox Developer Edition. I have had some other unusual issues before.

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I don't know what Firefox Developer Edition is, but try to check "Disable cache" when developer tools is enabled. Or install "Webdeveloper Toolbar" addon from Chris Prederick (https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/web-developer/) that allows you to disabling entire cache.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!